# FF loads CSS differently on refresh

Tags: css, firefox, refresh

I've added a little jQuery enabled promotional ad to the header of our website.  Debugged it in FF and verified that it's working in IE.  I start going around the office and noticed that in FF, whenever a person hits the page "for the first time only", the position of the ad is not correct (using absolute positioning). Refresh the page and it will load as I expected / intended for it to load.  IE seems to be working.  Anyone have any idea why FF would render differently on refresh when I didn't make any code changes?

http://stormsmart.com

Comment: Was there a previous version of the site, perhaps they have an old cached .css?  Or does this happen every non-refresh load in firefox?

Comment: Works ok for me. Are you sure it's not to do with any extensions running? You can run Firefox in Safe Mode to confirm this. Also, what version of FireFox is giving you the problem?

Comment: @nick.  Yes there was a previous version of the site.  You're saying that it probably loaded the old css file from cache.. ok.  I'm just concerned that new visitors are not seeing what I intended. 
It only happens the first load but the computers that I've tested on have all been to the site before so it loading a cached css file would make sense.

Comment: @Graham.. 3.5.7 is the version that i've seen the issue happen on but I think @nick hit on it.  If you're loading ok in ff then I'm guessing it's a cache issue.  thanks for the tips though.  didn't know about the ff safemode.

Answer (score 1):

One option keeping it simple is a query string, look how SO does this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=6322">
```

Just stick a query string that changes when you do a release on there...used for nothing but browser cache invalidation.  This will make browsers fetch a new copy when you change it.

I use this and modify it as part of our build process, the query string is the
`?v=Major.Minor.Rev.Changeset`  When we do a production push, client get new CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Are you giving the image a size (height/width)? If not, depending on placement, browsers don't know the size of the image and place it somewhere it thinks it fits but may not be what you have in mind. If you hit refresh, it already knows the size of the image and then "fixes" it.